# Insert into 2 related tables from a single SELECT using POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to move data from a single table `cc` into 2 tables `aa` and `bb` related by a foreign key:

```
Table cc
====
data_a, data_b


Table aa
====
id, data_a


Table bb
====
id, data_b, aa_id
```

Table `bb` has a foreign key `aa_id`. I need to create a row in `aa` with `cc.data_a` and a row in `bb` with `cc.data_b` and the newly created `aa.id`.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
with ar as (
      insert into aa (data_a)
         select distinct data_a
         from cc
         returning *
     )
insert into bb (data_b, aa_id)
    select cc.data_b, ar.id
    from cc join
         ar
         on cc.data_a = ar.data_a;
```

This assumes that you have defined `a` and `b` in advance with `serial` `id` columns.

Comment: Does it not require `data_a` to be unique? I probably should have specified that the data doesn't satisfy this condition. It's important to maintain the pairings of `data_a` and `data_b` but the data could be anything.

Comment: @NewDev . . . `select distinct` ensures that `a` has unique values in `data_a`.

Comment: I see. I guess I oversimplified the example. I need each row in `cc` to create a new row in both `aa` and `bb`, regardless of whether there may be duplicates in data. In real-world problem there are many columns of data.

Comment: @NewDev . . . Why would you want duplicates in `aa`?  That just doesn't make sense.  The purpose of splitting into multiple tables is to reduce the number of duplicates.

Comment: table `cc` is seed data into `aa` and `bb` that have other columns, in which the data will need to evolve independently.